# Должно создаваться 4 значения - с объектами срабатывает, а с числами нет

Tags: c++

Создаются 2 массива:

1. Массив объектов класса Card - таблицы с числами.
2. Главные числа этого массива, в данном случае степени двойки.

Должно создаваться 4 значения. С объектами срабатывает, а с числами нет.

Код:

```
int* AllNumList;
int Cmin=0, Cmax=0;
void Game()
{
    bool end = 0;
    int numOfIterations = 0;
    int maxNum = 1;
    while (maxNum <= Cmax)
    {
        numOfIterations++;
        maxNum = pow(2, numOfIterations);
    }
    numOfIterations--;
    maxNum = pow(2, numOfIterations);
    Card* card = new Card [numOfIterations +1];
    AllNumList = new int [numOfIterations+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfIterations;i++)
    {
        AllNumList[i] = pow(2, i);
        card[i].AddGenNumber(pow(2, i));
    }
}
```

Первая итерация цикла:

[image: Экранный снимок]

Последняя итерация:

[image: Экранный снимок]

Comment: Может, у вас в `AddGenNumber` ошибка... вы же ее текст не приводите.

Comment: Точно не в ней. Причем тут вообще класс Card? Он же отлично работает, как видно из кадра стека.

Comment: Как видно из скриншота, массиву присваевается лишь 1 возможное значение.

Comment: Если создавать переменную глобально - не работает. Внутри функции - работает. Но мне нужна глобальная переменная.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте вопросу нормальное название, отражающее суть проблемы

Comment: Тут сплошное UB. Содержимое `while (1 <= 0)` не исполняется ни разу. Выделение через `new` превращется в ересь: `new Card [0]`, `new int [0]` - запрос на выделение нуля объектов. Далее в исполняющемся один раз `for` идет обращение к выделенному нулю объектов.

Comment: Пересмотрел, `for` тоже не исполняется ни разу, там идет `0 <= -1`.

Comment: @Ternvein посмотрите внимательнее на скриншот: количество итераций = 3, а не -1.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а вы можете объяснить по коду, каким образом оно стало равно 3? (это не сарказм) В таком случае код явно не полный.

Comment: @Ternvein ну конечно же он не полный. Cmax - это ж глобальная переменная, любая другая функция могла установить ей значение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, в очередной раз зарекаюсь давать ответы на вопросы с неплоным кодом и скриншотами.

Comment: @Ternvein с помощью вариаций степени двойки возможно создать любое число. Человек указывает диапазон, в котором находится его число. Программа заполняет карточки, потом выводит их на экран. Пользователь нажимает на y(es)/n(o) если там есть загаданное число или нет соответственно. В итоге программа выводит загаданное число. Пример работы: http://snap.ashampoo.com/OPlfBDfj
С большим диапазоном еще дает ошибки из-за того, что по другому построен алгоритм. Сейчас это исправляю.

Comment: Должно работать приблизительно так: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQZmZRE0cQY

Comment: Совершенно не понятно, о чем идет речь в вопросе. То такое "должно создаться 4 значения"? О какой "логике" идет речь? Что такое "срабатывает" и "не срабатывает"? Пепеписывайте вопрос с нуля по порядку или удаляйте его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас обманул отладчик. Дело в том, что `AllNumList` с точки зрения системы типов - это не массив, а указатель. А на указателе не написано на сколько элементов он указывает. Обычно указатели указывают на один элемент - его отладчик вам и показывает.

Попробуйте в отладчике явно посмотреть `AllNumList[1]`, `AllNumList[2]` и `AllNumList[3]` - там вы найдете все те числа которые потеряли.

Comment: (раз уж вопрос подняли — может, и заголовок более адекватный напишет кто-нибудь?)

Comment: @andreymal я попробовал, но имхо, вопрос очень низкого качества и тут только ТС или Pavel Mayorov могли бы его причесать до соответствия ответу (сделать MCVE)

Comment: @Kromster не представляю как его причёсывать...